# Domain of a variable and equations involving complex numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my book, **Domain of a variable** is defined as the set of all possible real numbers for which the term involving that variable is a real number.

Next to it, **Solution Set** is defined as the set containing all real numbers as in the domain of the variable for which given equation involving that variable is satisfied.

Let $$x=2i$$

These definitions, simultaneously, implies $$S.S=\emptyset$$

However solution set exists having $2i$.

I guess there must be more general definition of Domain. If anyone of you know, share it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loosely speaking, a domain is a set from which values can be taken and put into a function. You're right, it **does not** have to be the set of all real numbers $\mathbb R$, or even the set of complex numbers $\mathbb C$. I could even have some function $f$ that has $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ be the domain. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function).